# Android- Radiogroup

Tags: android

I've created multiple Radiogroup with radio buttons and add this into a tablerow dynamically. It's working fine. 
After that i've add `rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. Then i store the id of radio button in an array. For first time this works fine after that multiple click the radiogroup messed. It show selected more than one button. Why it is happening ? How can i solve this.

My sample code here:

```
//get count of array 
int count = get_count_of_array();
for(int toi=0; toi<count; toi++) {
    // Creating radiogrup
    // creating table row
    // craeting radio buttons
    // set id, layoutparams and all the details
    // Add these views to layout
    // get position from array
    rg.check(Integer.parseInt(array_2.get(toi)));
}
```

Comment: The "sample code" you've included doesn't have enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It might because of the ID of the button ..
When Id is stored then array have more than one record of same data

Try

radioGroup.clearCheck();

Comment: I've check the array . Inserted values are correct. have any other idea?